# Grunt twice for the same task

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

I would like to run the [**`jshint`**](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) task twice in [**`GruntJS`**](http://gruntjs.com/), but with different options each time.

How would I go about doing something like that?

Currently, my `Gruntfile.js` looks like this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var opts = {
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        jasmine_node: {
            matchall: true,
            forceExit: true
        },
        jshint: {
            files: [
                'gruntfile.js',
                'src/**/*.js', '!src/static/bin', '!src/static/js/libs/*.js',
                'test/spec/**/*.js'
            ],
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            }
        }
    };

    grunt.initConfig(opts);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jasmine-node');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'jasmine_node']);
    grunt.registerTask('travis', ['jshint', 'jasmine_node']);
};
```

And I would probably want it to be something like this:

```
var jshint: {
    files: [
        'gruntfile.js',
        'src/**/*.js', '!src/static/**',
        'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
    options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
    }
}

var jshint2 = {
    files: [
        'src/static/**/*.js',
        '!src/static/bin',
        '!src/static/js/libs/*.js'
    ],
    options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc-browser'
    }
};
```

So that I can pick different options for the front-end javascript and the NodeJS javascript, since linting should be different for each of those environments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jshint` is a [multitask](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks). So it is possible to have to following config:

```
jshint: {
  browser: {
    files: [
        'src/static/**/*.js',
        '!src/static/bin',
        '!src/static/js/libs/*.js'
    ],
    options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc-browser'
    }
  },
  node: {
    files: [
        'gruntfile.js',
        'src/**/*.js', '!src/static/**',
        'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
    options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
    }
  }
}
```

To run the **browser version**:

`grunt jshint:browser`.

To run to **node version**:

`grunt jshint:node`.

Running just:

`grunt jshint`

will run both.

Of course, you probably will want to trigger them via another task, e.g:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean:all', 'jshint:browser', ...]);
```

You want want to read the section [**Specifying JSHint options and globals**](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint#specifying-jshint-options-and-globals) for more info.